# Замена числа на слово

Tags: php, html

Допустим имеется переменная `$test` и в ней хранится число от 1 до 3.

У меня цель сделать замену текста так что бы когда в переменной `$test` какое то из чисел то число заменялось на слово.

```
elseif($test == '3'){ echo "Проверка";}
```

Через функцию `explode` у меня не получается,просто не могу понять как она работает.

Comment: $arr=array(1,2,3); foreach($arr as $key =>$value){if($value=="1"){ echo "Один";}elseif($value=="2"){echo"два";}else{echo "три";}}

Comment: А причем тут explode?

Comment: если хотите заменить в массиве значение то используйте array_replace() вставляйте в условие и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложите ваши слова в массив,  и выводите оттуда по ключу в `$test`

```
$arr = [ 1 => 'слово-1', 2 => 'слово-2', 3 => 'Проверка'];

if(array_key_exists($test, $arr){
    echo $arr[$test];
}
```

в целом, если вы уверены, что такой ключ точно будет в массиве. то проверку `array_key_exists` можно опустить

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "123";
$test[0] = "word"; // меняем 1 на word
echo $test[0];
```